# Is it possible to convert System.currentTimeinMillis to Date

Tags: java

I have a Field in Mongo DB called as updated_at

Which will look in DB this way

updated_at : NumberLong("1355754242785")

This Updated_at filed is created in Database this way

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

From one of the DB Record , i have taken a value as

```
updated_at" : NumberLong("1355754242785"), "volatility12" : "na", "vwap" : "0", "wk52hi" : "0", "wk52hidate" : "----"}
```

For example say its value is 1355754242785

Is it possible to convert the 1355754242785 , when this was Updated ??

When i tried converting

```
public class Aim {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        long now = 1355754242785; // Error here saying out of range 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(now);
        System.out.println(now + " = " + formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `long now = 1355754242785L;`, with the L on the end, to tell it that it's long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
  long now = 1355754242785; // Error here saying out of range
```

to

```
long now = 1355754242785L;
```

This is a compilation error, for the assignment; that should give you a clue that the problem has nothing to do with dates, just with the fact that a literal number in Java is assumed to be an `int`, which have a maximum value of `2^31-1` . You must add the `L` suffix to tell Java that the literal is to be interpreted as a `long`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just use the [`Date(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor, which receives the time in millisecods as parameter. Do something like this:

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Which incidentally, is equivalent to simply writing this:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long now = 1355754242785L;
Date nowAsDate = new Date(now);
```